# Is possible to create "Tanaka contours" by Matplotlib?

Tags: python, matplotlib, contourf

I need to create graph which will look like this example. 
[image: Tanaka contours]

Now I am using very similar solution by this code:

```
plt.contourf(xi, yi, zi,15, cmap=plt.cm.Reds,alpha=0.5, vmin=0, vmax=0.1)
plt.contour(xi, yi, zi, 15, colors='k',alpha=1, linewidths=0.4, vmin=0, vmax=0.1)
```

This is how it looks like:
[image: actual solution]

Is somehow possible to use "tanaka contours" (very similar to terrain) in Matplotlib?

Comment: quick google search. Have you tried to start [here](https://anitagraser.com/2015/05/24/how-to-create-illuminated-contours-tanaka-style/)?

Comment: Matplotlib has some example code [here](https://matplotlib.org/examples/specialty_plots/topographic_hillshading.html) for a similar problem.